# Replace <span text-decoration:underline with <u></u>

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am formatting a certain html text.

In that text I have several `<span>` tags with various attributes.
I want to change all

```
<span style="text-decoration: underline; color: #993300;">XXXXXXX</span>
```

with

```
<span style="color:#993300"><u>XXXXXXXX</span>
```

I used

```
$cont = preg_replace("/<span style=\"text-decoration:\s(.+?)>(.+?)<\/span>/is", "<u>$2</u>", $cont);
```

to achieve that. But the problem is that if I have multiple `</span>` tags, then the script will replace everything between the `<span style="...` and the last `</span>`

Please help.

Comment: Maybe http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html, section: "Greedy and Lazy Repetition" could help.

Comment: see https://regex101.com/r/iQ0pU7/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
preg_replace("/(<span\s*style\s*=\s*\"[^\"]*?)text-decoration\s*:\s*underline\s*;([^\"]*\"\s*>)((.(?!<\/span>))+)<\/span>/is", "$1$2<u>$3</u><\/span>")
```

Where the idea is to match every character until `</span>`with

```
(.(?!<\/span>))+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by using `JQuery`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('span').css('color', '#993300');
    $('span').css('text-decoration', 'none');
});
</script>
```

If you are new on `JQuery` than include `jQuery` library ist in `<head>` like this example:

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Now you can use the **above code**, it will work.

Comment: Now I am using 

 $cont = preg_replace("/<span style=\"color:\s#000000;\">(.+?)<\/span>/is", "$1", $cont);
 $cont = preg_replace("/<span style=\"(.+?)>(.+?)<\/span>/is", "<b><u>$2</u></b>", $cont);

Comment: @DevTest: why with preg_replace?, my answer is not working?

Comment: Actually, I am not well with JavaScript/jQuery :-)
I don't know how to use that, and asking u to help to do that is asking too much :-)

Comment: @DevTest: my friend just copy javascript code and paste in the bottom of your page, and i suppose you already have included the jquery library is it?

Comment: >>and i suppose you already have included the jquery library is it?<<    Nope dear :-)

As i said, am not acquainted with jquery at all. I am just a beginner with php only, but love to learn new things :-)

Can I just copy paste the above code without any further settings? or after a jQuery initialization settings?

Comment: Thanks buddy, let me check it

Comment: @Devtest did I checked